# blueJ kareltje making ports in world

Tags: java, bluej

Kareltje needs to walk trough the maze

Now I would like to create a list of coordinates that Kareltje must find. These coordinates are ports (walls).
When Kareltje walking to this ports, it puts a wall down so he can not go back.
My problem is that I don't know how to make the walls and coordinates. Can someone help me with this?

**This is the code I got now:**

```
import wereld.Robot;

public class OefenRobot4 extends Robot  {

    boolean finish = false;

    public OefenRobot4(String naam)
    {
        super(naam);
    }

    public void hoofdProgramma()
      {
          vraagBegin();
          Verplaatsen();
          Lopen();
      }

    public String vraagBegin() {
        String deVraag = vraagTekst("Wil je karel helpen zodat de piepbal op zijn plek terecht komt?");
            if(deVraag.equalsIgnoreCase("ja"))
                {
                    zeg ("Oke laten we snel gaan beginnen!");
                }
            else if(deVraag.equalsIgnoreCase("nee"))
                {
                    zeg("Kareltje is verdrietig want zijn piepbal kan hij nu niet terugbrengen ");
                }
    return deVraag;
    }

    public void Verplaatsen(){

      if(pos_x==1&&pos_y==1)
        {
            mijnWereld.verplaats(this, 26,19);
            piepbalMeenemen();
        }

    }

      public void Lopen() {

          while(finish != true) {
              int D = dobbel();

              switch (D) {
                case 1: linksom();
                        break;
                case 2: rechtsom();
                        break;
                default: if (!voorObstakel()) {
                          stap();
                          positieControle();
                         }
                        break;

                }

        }
    }

       public boolean piepbalMeenemen() {
        opPiepbal();
            {
                pakPiepbal();
            }
        return heeftPiepbal();
    }

    public void positieControle()
    {
        if (pos_x==1&&pos_y==1)
            {
                legPiepbal();

                zeg("Ik heb de piepbal terug gebracht!");
            }
    }
}
```

**And this is the code from de oefenwereld:**

```
// Code voorbeeld voor een robot met de naam Kareltje

import wereld.*;

public class OefenWereld4 extends Wereld
{

    OefenRobot4 robot;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        OefenWereld4 wereld = new OefenWereld4();
    }

    public OefenWereld4()
    {
        super(myworld);
        setSlaaptijd(1);
        robot = new OefenRobot4("Kareltje");
        plaats(robot, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you, we also need the code that comprises the Wereld and 
Robot classes.